# How to change color based on another celss value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file were we track our daily work. I want to compare two dates and color mark the cell if the dates compares differ with more than 7 days. I calculated the different between the dates and put the result in another cell. Based on that value I want to color mark the date. But my formula is not working. Im using this formula (se attached picture). Im comparing the date from row 7 with teh date from row 10 and put the result in row 14. q14 should not be red as the result is lowe than 7. What Im I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Q` column in you picture. But the problem in formula `=$D$14:$S$14>7` is absolute references (`$`). You should just use relative reference `=D14>7`, it will "move" right to `E14`, `F14` and so on for all range you chose to format:

[image]

Also you can use direct calculation `=(D7-D10)>7`:

[image]